# Play audio when checkbox is checked with javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, checkbox

I'm trying to make a short audio file play when a html checkbox is checked. I'm probably missing something elementary.
Here is my code:

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cena" onchange="myfunction()"></input><label for="cena"></label>
</label><script>
function myfunction(){
var audio = new audio('rusbtaudio.mp3');
audio.play();
}
</script>
    </body>
```

`rusbtaudio.mp3` is in same folder as html file.

Comment: Never mind the extra </label>

Comment: It should be `new Audio(...)`... and you should check for checked, not on change

Comment: `<input>` element is self-closing. Use `canplay` event. Instead of creating `new Audio()` at each `change` event you can use `.load()`

Comment: Can you elaborate on that, please?

Comment: I have to excuse myself, my knowledge on javascript is minimal. We havent started on javascript in my IT course yet, and css wasnt capable of this simple task. I'd really appreciate seeing the changes I have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<input>` element is self-closing. Use `.load()`, `canplay` event. Substitute `new Audio()` for `new audio()`

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cena" onchange="myfunction(this)" />
    <label for="cena"></label>
    <script>
       var audio = new Audio('rusbtaudio.mp3');
       audio.oncanplay = function() {
       if (document.getElementById("cena").checked) this.play()
       }
       function myfunction(el) {    
         if (el.checked) {
           audio.load();
         }
       }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: When the audio pauses?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript:

```
var audio = new Audio('rusbtaudio.mp3'),
    cenaCheckbox = document.getElementById('cena'),
    myfunction = function () {
      if (cenaCheckbox.checked) {
        audio.play();
      }
    };
```

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cena" onchange="myfunction();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

hello  you should try this one

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cena" onclick="myfunction()"></input><label   
for="cena"></label>
</label>

<script>
function myfunction(){
var audio = new Audio('sel.mp3');
audio.play();
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. For one, `input` is self-closing. Second of all, they want *when checked*, not every time it is clicked!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct! The only problem is in this line:

```
new audio('rusbtaudio.mp3');
```

Just change `audio` to `Audio` - check out [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement)

Also there some issues with tags, such as redundant `</input>` and unneeded second `</label>` but even though it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the following error Uncaught TypeError: audio is not a constructor, try this code, native JavaScript with HTML5 audio tag

HTML

```
<body>
  <audio id="audio1" hidden="hidden">Canvas not supported</audio>
  <input type="hidden" id="audioFile" value="rusbtaudio.mp3" size="60" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="playbutton" onclick="togglePlay();">Play
</body>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    // Create a couple of global variables to use. 
    var audioElm = document.getElementById("audio1"); // Audio element     

    //  Alternates between play and pause based on the value of the paused property
    function togglePlay() {
      if (document.getElementById("audio1")) {
        if (audioElm.paused == true) {
          playAudio(audioElm);    //  if player is paused, then play the file
        } else {
          pauseAudio(audioElm);   //  if player is playing, then pause
        }
      }
    }
    function playAudio(audioElm) {
      // Get file from text box and assign it to the source of the audio element 
      audioElm.src = document.getElementById('audioFile').value;
      audioElm.play();
    }

    function pauseAudio(audioElm) {
      audioElm.pause();
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth adding a pause function to the checkbox (not all users like background music). I did it

```
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="cena" onchange="myfunction(this)" />
    <label for="cena"></label>
    <script>
       var audio = new Audio('rusbtaudio.mp3');
       audio.oncanplay = function() {
       if (document.getElementById("cena").checked) this.play()
       }
       function myfunction(el) {    
         if (el.checked) {
           audio.load();
         } else {
           audio.pause(); //pause audio
         }
       }
</script>
</body>
```